# Noun describing when one acquires a large amount of capital in a short period of time

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm convinced I read the dictionary definition of a word like this before, now I am going insane trying to find it again.  Any ideas what I'm thinking of?

Comment: When a question asks for help remembering something you have forgotten, it is subjective – a request for guesses or ideas, with the key criterion for answer correctness hidden in the mind of the asker. Unfortunately this is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective enough to have a clearly “right” answer no matter who is asking. Otherwise, the answer is not useful to future visitors, and we are guessing when we answer or cast votes.

Comment: See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”, and “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”. A welcoming place to ask for help remembering a word you have forgotten is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95). 
Also check out: “[Tip of My Tongue](http://chir.ag/projects/tip-of-my-tongue/)” dictionary search, “[TOMT](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/)” subreddit.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "windfall", where a large amonunt unexpectedly falls into your lap, such as an inheritance.

Comment: And the word was "bonanza", a synonym of windfall :).  Thank's so much!